# Symfony2 routing optional parameter and format path/pattern

Tags: symfony, routes, pattern-matching

I would like to construct the following URI's using a single route pattern

```
1 hello/first.format
2 hello/first
3 hello/first/last.format
4 hello/first/last
```

where **first** is required and **last** and **format** are optional.

this is what I have tried:

```
hello-route:
  pattern:  /hello/{fist_name}/{last_name}.{_format}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index, last_name:Default, _format:html}
requirements:
  _format: html|rss|json
  first_name: \w+
  last_name: \w+
```

But is not correct as it matches 2, 3, and 4 but not 1. 1 will not fail, but it will match {first_name} as "first.format" despite the requirement.

How can I do this using basic routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define two routes to accomplish this

```
hello-route-first:
  pattern:  /hello/{fist_name}.{_format}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index, _format:html}
requirements:
  _format: html|rss|json
  first_name: \w+

hello-route-last:
  pattern:  /hello/{fist_name}/{last_name}.{_format}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index, _format:html}
requirements:
  _format: html|rss|json
  first_name: \w+
  last_name: \w+
```

Then make the $last_name argument optional in your controller

```
function indexAction($first_name, $last_name = "")
   {
```